# XMPP framework - Location based app connected in background

Tags: iphone, background, xmppframework

I developed and app that is currently set as "Location based" so that it can run in the background indefenitely. It's not a trick i need it to do stuff when the user moves.
After some search I learned that this app will only execute code on the event of a location change, no timer whatsoever will be able to execute any code after 10 mins.

My app, while in the background, stays connected to XMPP for 50mins or so, it then disconnects.  I would like the app to never disconnect, I looked at the framework but I can't find the place where to fix this behaviour. Do you know if it's possible to stay connected "indefinetly"? if so what settings do I have to change in the xmppframework.

thanks

[EDIT]
After 50mins the user is still connected to XMPP but it's disconnected of the XMPPRooms it was conected.
On another run it was connected for 3 hours, the time the iPhone is connected doesnt seem to be consistent.

Comment: If it's disconnected from the XMPPRooms only, then it might have something to do with your sessions maintained at back-end which last for 50 mins.

Comment: I have set my server to : _Do not disconnect clients that are idle._
What setting do you mean?

Comment: I meant sessions for rooms, if they're different from user sessions. You've mentioned in your edit that the user session is maintained but the XMPPRooms are disconnected

Comment: I've checked in the settings of the server and I can't see anything to set sessions in XMPPRooms.
Also I've see how the phone can be connected to the rooms for 3 hours, so that 50mins is not something fix.

Comment: hmm...you can consider putting this up for a bounty...somebody else might be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your application can do send and receive keep-alive messages, it needs to be a voip app and use a voip socket. From [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW27):

> 1. Add the UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file. Set the value of this key to an array that includes the voip value.
> 2. Configure one of the app’s sockets for VoIP usage.
> 3. Before moving to the background, call the setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method to install a handler to be executed periodically. Your app can use this handler to maintain its service connection.

As for the socket:

> NSInputStream and NSOutputStream: For Cocoa streams, use the setProperty:forKey: method to add the NSStreamNetworkServiceType property to the stream. The value of this property should be set to NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP.